# onKeyDown and finish() triggers "Google Now"

Tags: android, google-now

Why if I use the following code to exit my app, roughly 80% of the times after the app is closed "Google Now" opens?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (something) {
            //do mystuff
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Extra info: the App runs in Landscape, I use a similar code on other apps that doesn't force the orientation an this issue doesn't occur. On a tablet (that has landscape as default) "Google Now" never opened once.

FYI : I solved my issue by using onBackpressed() but I still like to know what is wrong with that code or if it is some sort of bug.

Comment: I set some layers visibility and run an AnimationSet, but that should't matter because it isn't called when the app is closed (finish()).

Comment: I know on my Nexus 5 (4.4.2) if I hold down on the back/home/options button I can swipe up to open Google Now, could that be what your doing?

Comment: No, also you don't need to "hold down" the swipe gesture from the bottom is enough.

Comment: Got any solution, same happening to me on 5.1.1